# soap service The specified type was not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, soap

Can anyone tell me why I get:

```
{"The specified type was not recognized: name='anyType', namespace='http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/service.wsdl', at <response xmlns=''>."}
```

And the xml that I'm getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/service.wsdl" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:getCarsResponse>
      <response SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:anyType[2]" xsi:type="ns1:carlist">
        <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
          <id xsi:type="xsd:string">1392</id>
          <merk xsi:type="xsd:string">Citroen</merk>
          <type xsi:type="xsd:string">C1</type>
          <uitvoering xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0i Selection 5D</uitvoering>
          <leaseprijs xsi:type="xsd:string">299,--</leaseprijs>
          <looptijd xsi:type="xsd:string">18</looptijd>
          <kilometrage xsi:type="xsd:string">25.000</kilometrage>
          <thumbnail xsi:type="xsd:string">/i_upload/free/_th.gif</thumbnail>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
          <id xsi:type="xsd:string">1393</id>
          <merk xsi:type="xsd:string">Citroen</merk>
          <type xsi:type="xsd:string">C1</type>
          <uitvoering xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0i Selection 5D</uitvoering>
          <leaseprijs xsi:type="xsd:string">299,--</leaseprijs>
          <looptijd xsi:type="xsd:string">18</looptijd>
          <kilometrage xsi:type="xsd:string">25.000</kilometrage>
          <thumbnail xsi:type="xsd:string">/i_upload/free/_th.gif</thumbnail>
        </item>
      </response>
    </SOAP-ENV:getCarsResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I invoke the SOAP service in this way:

```
Service.service_portClient proxy = new Service.service_portClient();
proxy.getCars("Citroen", benzine);
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue ? I am getting the similar exception while consuming 3rd party api in my .net code.

Comment: @MSUH: Yup, the issue was that in the response that I've got from 3rd part api there were some types that were not defined in the *.wsdl file